# Can I lock an element in a list to make it threadsafe, instead of locking the whole list?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I would store objects in my std list on thread-safe way. I don't want to block a thread, if it want to access an element that currently not in use.
If I can't lock only one element, there is an other question: If I call a destructor on one of my object in the list, will it remove the element and invalidate it's iterator?

Comment: Could you briefly explain why you need this (what you're doing), how the lifetime of the objects in the list is and how the threads operate on the list (e.g. iterate over the whole or something else and how do they know which item to work on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you need to protect the whole list container instance by a lock or mutex in multi threaded environment.

If you are storing new'ed objects in your container, then the destructor will be called only when you are deleting the pointer to the object.

Further answer to your question depends upon:

1. What are you storing in list ? Object itself or Pointer to object

2. "If I call a destructor on one of my object in the list"... Does this mean Deleting the list node or retrieving the pointer from list and then deleting it instead of deleting the list node [This is not good unless you point the pointer to NULL] .

If you are storing object itself the list.remove will call destructor for the object.

If you are storing pointer to the object .. list.remove will not call destructor and I think its a no-op as well [correct me if I am wrong here]

3. The standard gives a guaratee that list iterator will not be invalidated on addition and splicing ... but will become invalid if the iterator pointing to the removed element.

Comment: "If you are storing new'ed objects in your container, then the destructor will be called only when you are deleting the pointer to the object." I know that. But what's happen, when I call the destructor manually?

Comment: @Alexander, calling destructors directly is generally not such a good idea. In your example, if you do that you'll free the memory, but the list stays the same with an entry to that object (now freed), so you'll end up with undefined behavior. Not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for murrekatt's great comment, too.

Comment: @murrekatt: "if you [call destructor manually] you'll free the memory" - no.  For illustrative purposes, say the `list` holds a pointer to an object which is a `struct` with a `const char*` member to a heap-allocated ASCIIZ string.  The destructor might well free the ASCIIZ string, but the memory used by the object itself will not be freed simply by calling its destructor.  If a placement `new` is immediately used to create another object (of the same type) in the same location, behaviour won't be undefined.  But you're right - it's not a good idea: too finicky.

Comment: @Tony, I don't quite get your point. If the list has pointers to a struct std::list<MyStruct*> and someone calls the destructor of one of them, the object's memory is freed (assuming it can destroy itself properly). The list will still have a pointer to that location, but it will be dangling. And yes, if someone creates a new (same) object in the same place to where the list pointer points to you will not really be in undefined behavior. Maybe I missed  what you meant?

Comment: @murrekatt: Will see if I can explain it better....  "someone calls the destructor...memory is freed"... no - the memory is not "freed".  "Freed" is a heap allocation term implying the memory is released back to the heap.  Calling a destructor gives the object a chance to release any resources it managed, but doesn't "free" the memory it is itself stored in.  After destruction, it's like stack memory for local variables after a scope exits - there's effectively garbage values from the destroyed objects.  But, for list, you must erase to have list `delete` the element & return mem to the heap.

Comment: @Tony, OK, maybe I got mixed up in "calling the destructor" in this case. I don't do that really. :) In the case of pointers it would be `delete p;` for a struct in the list. This leaves a dangling pointer in the list.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I lock an element in a list to make it threadsafe, instead of locking the whole list?

Yes, if all threads use a lock whenever reading/writing/destructing the element, then that is safe.

For example, if the element was a `string`, and one thread took the lock, appended a character, then released the lock, then another thread can:

- safely attempt to do the same, to the same element, contesting the same lock
- append a different element to the list without any lock
- **NOT** do a `find()` in the `list`; the `find` may attempt a read on the partially updated string
- **NOT** `sort()` the list
- **NOT** `erase()` the element from the list

> I don't want to block a thread, if it want to access an element that currently not in use.

Well, you need some level of granularity.  The finest possible is a lock per element, but that's potentially very wasteful of space (and wasted memory eventually impacts performance).

> If I can't lock only one element, there is an other question: If I call a destructor on one of my object in the list, will it remove the element and invalidate it's iterator?

No.  Calling a destructor doesn't normally affect the list (unless your elements themselves are aware of the list holding them and their destructors are coded to remove themselves).  Normally, you instead `erase` the element from the list and that calls the destructor and releases the associated heap memory.  If the element is itself a raw pointer, then you need to call `delete` on it yourself (smart_pointer's automated that for you).  Iterators, pointer, references to the erased element are immediated invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate The List, you should LOCK around The List.  Once your object is extracted, you can release The List Lock, and LOCK around the object only.